# Angular: Change templateUrl & styleUrls on NG serve and Deploy

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base code that I implements on many customers with a custom style&template for each one.
on each component I have a configuration like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './customer1.header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customer1.header.component.scss']
})
```

Every time I have to work on a different customer I have to manually change templateUrl/styleUrls on each component.

All answers that I have found that tries to solve this are for dynamically change the template when the code is already deployed, that means to deploy all templates to all my customers, not plausible.

I would like to set an enviroment variable to set the customer template and use it when running ng serve or when I deploy the code for an specific customer.

Answer (score 1):

When angular compiles it changes the templateUrl and styleUrls into code.
So it won't be possible to change them at runtime in the way you are doing it.

Depending on how much custom code you have for each customer you could solve it in a couple of ways.

## One solution could be

Using the fileReplacements function from angular cli you could create an file for each customer.

```
// customers/customer.customer1.ts
export const customer = {
  customerName: 'Customer 1'
}
```

and in your angular.json you add an configuration for each customer

```
// angular.json
"myappname": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "configurations": {
            "customer1": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/myappname/src/customers/customer.ts",
                  "with": "apps/myappname/src/customers/customer.customer1.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
```

then when you build you can set the configuration

```
ng build --configuration="production,customer1"
```

## Another solution

create a header component for each customer and lazy load them using `ngComponentOutlet`
https://netbasal.com/welcome-to-the-ivy-league-lazy-loading-components-in-angular-v9-e76f0ee2854a